# JAR to include to run cordapp

Tags: corda

I am following the tutorial to build the docker image of corda given in [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/running-corda-dlt-with-kubernetes-3f21c15d4dd8) and also referring to [this](https://github.com/corda/corda-docker). after building the base image as given in the first link, the instruction given was to add cordapps jar into an folder. I am confused whether to use jar present in `kotlin-source/build/libs` folder or the `runnodes` jar present in `kotlin-source/build/nodes` folder. it would be helpful if some one guides through it.

Answer (score 0):

the cordapp jars contain the code that you wrote and will therefore be in `kotlin-source/build/libs` or wherever the jars you build are going to. `runnodes` is generated by the `deployNodes` script and just used as a way to start the nodes.

The other important jar is the `corda.jar` without this nothing will work.

Comment: FYI - instead of using `deployNodes`, you can simply use `gradlew jar` to create the CorDapp JARs (as described here: https://docs.corda.net/cordapp-build-systems.html#creating-the-cordapp-jar).

Comment: while adding new node with existing netowrk, after running the bootstrapper, all folders and infos are updated. but can't see the corda jar in new node's  cordapps folder. whether we have to update manually or automatically gets updated?